# XUnit.net capture the result of each test right after it runs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

I am attempting to use XUnit.net as a replacement for a custom home-grown test scheduler.  One of the features of the home grown scheduler is that for tests which are long-running, it outputs the result of the test (pass/fail, as well as the exception which caused the failure) to a database right after the test passes/fails.

Because there are a possible large number of long running tests this is useful in order to view test progress over the course of a run (don't have to wait for the full test pass until you see all the results, as the full test pass may take time).

The XUnit.net source is here: https://github.com/xunit/xunit

I've taken a look and see [BeforeAfterTestAttribute](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/b2c6201025f71ede57c0e9cc1f0ad31ee828dbfb/src/xunit.core/Sdk/BeforeAfterTestAttribute.cs), but the "After" method doesn't give access to the test results, just to the test method.  I want something similar but which also gives access to the test result, so that I can report to a database the result immediately (instead of having to wait for the full test suite to finish).

It seems (from source) that the only thing that has access to the actual test result is the [TestRunner](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/8d4e6b68caa7c7e875ac4db72e4c87f4b12c0155/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/Frameworks/Runners/TestRunner.cs), but as far as I can tell there is no extensibility model for the test runner.

One possible workaround I've come up with is the following:

```
[Fact]
TestMethod()
{
    //This method takes a lambda, handles exceptions, uploads to my
    //database, and then rethrows.
    RunTestWithExtraLogging(() => 
    {
        //Actual test goes here
    }
}
```

The above solution isn't ideal though as it requires the author of each test to call the "RunTestWithExtraLogging" method.

PS: I'm open to considering a different test framework (other than xUnit.net) if it supports this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I believe you need to create you own runner. A simple example on how this can be done is provided below (you will need to add the logic you require in the `TestMethodRunnerCallback` method:

```
namespace MyTestRunner
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using Xunit;        

    public class Program
    {
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testAssembly = TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(
                new ExecutorWrapper(args[0], null, false));

            var tests = testAssembly.EnumerateTestMethods(x =>  x
                .DisplayName
                .ToLowerInvariant();

            var testMethods = (args.Length > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[1])
                ? tests.Contains(args[1].ToLowerInvariant())).ToList()
                : tests.ToList();

            if (testMethods.Count == 0)
                return 0;

            var runnerCallback = new TestMethodRunnerCallback();
            testAssembly.Run(testMethods, runnerCallback);

            return runnerCallback.FailedCount;
        }

        public class TestMethodRunnerCallback : ITestMethodRunnerCallback
        {
            public int FailedCount { get; private set; }

            public void AssemblyFinished(TestAssembly testAssembly, int total, int failed, int skipped, double time)
            {
                FailedCount = failed;
            }

            public void AssemblyStart(TestAssembly testAssembly)
            {
            }

            public bool ClassFailed(TestClass testClass, string exceptionType, string message, string stackTrace)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public void ExceptionThrown(TestAssembly testAssembly, Exception exception)
            {
            }

            public bool TestFinished(TestMethod testMethod)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public bool TestStart(TestMethod testMethod)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:**
It appears as though in xUnit.net 2.0 `TestAssemblyBuilder` has been replaced with `XunitFrontController`.  The code below shows a snippet of how to capture the result of a test pass as the tests are running:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string assemblyPath = @"path";
        XunitFrontController controller = new XunitFrontController(
            assemblyPath);

        TestAssemblyConfiguration assemblyConfiguration = new TestAssemblyConfiguration();

        ITestFrameworkDiscoveryOptions discoveryOptions = TestFrameworkOptions.ForDiscovery(assemblyConfiguration);
        ITestFrameworkExecutionOptions executionOptions = TestFrameworkOptions.ForExecution(assemblyConfiguration);

        IMessageSink messageSink = new CustomTestMessageVisitor<ITestMessage>();

        Console.WriteLine("Running tests");

        controller.RunAll(
            messageSink: messageSink,
            discoveryOptions: discoveryOptions,
            executionOptions: executionOptions);
    }
}

public class CustomTestMessageVisitor<T> : TestMessageVisitor<T> where T : ITestMessage
{
    protected override bool Visit(ITestFinished message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0} finished.",
            message.Test.DisplayName);
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool Visit(ITestPassed message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test {0} passed", message.Test.DisplayName);
        return true;
    }

    protected override bool Visit(ITestFailed message)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string exceptionType in message.ExceptionTypes)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}, ", exceptionType);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Test {0} failed with {1}", 
            message.Test.DisplayName, 
            stringBuilder.ToString());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of XUnit are you referencing -- when I try this I am not able to resolve TestAssemblyBuilder.

I also can't seem to find that class on GitHub either: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=TestAssemblyBuilder

I also cannot resolve ITestMethodRunnerCallback.

Are these interfaces/classes part of the XUnit NuGet package?

Comment: This uses `xunit.runner.utility.dll`, that used to be a part of http://xunitcontrib.codeplex.com/ and apparently is now moved to https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit

Comment: @Hydraxy Having a quick look at the current github repo, it seems there may be a different method preferred now: implementing an `XmlTestExecutionVisitor` instead of an `ITestMethodRunnerCallback`. This is used e.g. in the Asp.Net teststack, you may want to have a look at https://github.com/aspnet/Testing

Comment: From this page it seems as if xunit.runner.utility is the package which should contain the xunit.runner.utility.dll (http://xunit.github.io/docs/nuget-packages.html) -- but if I pull down that package I only get xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll which doesn't contain the type TestAssemblyBuilder.

I was able to find the TestAssemblyBuilder type in the location you originally mentioned in the 1.9.1 release: (https://xunit.codeplex.com/releases/view/90058)...

Do you know if there is a corresponding equivalent class in the new xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll?

Comment: It looks like in the new xunit.runner.utility.desktop.dll the type which replaced TestAssemblyBuilder is XunitFrontController.

Comment: @Hydraxy feel free to edit this answer to add the details you discovered, to make it a better answer for future readers searching to do the same.

Comment: Can the pass/failure result be accessed inside the Unit Test themselves via this custom runner, specifically in the Dispose() method?